# How to force an expression to be shown in terms of a specific function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I have an integral `inte1` as below:

```
f[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
F[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
inte1 = Integrate[f[x]*x^2, {x, -∞, k}] // FullSimplify
```

which is:

[image]

But I want to show it in terms of `F[x]`:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ComplexityFunction` to make expressions with `Erf` costly:

```
FullSimplify[inte1, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, _Erf, Infinity] &) ]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the second argument of `FullSimplify` or the option `Assumptions` to provide simplifying assumptions:

```
FullSimplify[inte1, F[-k] == HoldForm[F][-k]] (* or *)
FullSimplify[inte1, Assumptions->{F[-k] == HoldForm[F][-k]}]
```

[image]

```
% // TeXForm
```

> $-F(-k)-\frac{e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}} k}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+1$

You can also use `ReplaceAll` to replace `Erf` with an alternative form:

```
inte1 /. Erf -> (2 (1 - HoldForm[F][-Sqrt[2] #]) - 1 &)
```

> same output

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works for the above case, but failed for a slight variation. I tried `inte2 = Integrate[f[x]*x, {x, -k + b, k + b}] // FullSimplify` and `FullSimplify[inte2, f[k] == HoldForm[f][k]]`, but it doesn't give me the desired output `f[b - k] - f[b + k]`... How can I fix that?

Comment: @H42, i will post an update i figure out how to handle the case in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you define `F` with `F[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];` then `F` can never appear in any subsequent evaluated expression since the definition will have been applied.

```
Clear[f, F]

f[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
```

Use a [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) to express [`Erf`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Erf.html) in terms of `F`

```
rule = Erf[x_] -> 2 F[x Sqrt[2]] - 1;

inte1 = (Integrate[f[x]*x^2, {x, -∞, k}] // FullSimplify) /. rule

(* -((E^(-(k^2/2)) k)/Sqrt[2 π]) + F[k] *)
```

To evaluate `F` replace it with [`CDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html)

```
FullSimplify[inte1 /. F -> (CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #] &)]

(* -((E^(-(k^2/2)) k)/Sqrt[2 π]) + 1/2 (1 + Erf[k/Sqrt[2]]) *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Clear[F];
inte1 /. Erf[k/Sqrt[2]] -> 1 - 2 F[-k] // Simplify
```

giving exactly what you want.

Have fun!